# Changing a two-letter Country Code into numbers in Java

Tags: java

I'm quite new in Java and I'm having trouble with a project of mine. I'm trying to get a two-letter country code from a user (for example FR for France) which will then be converted into a specific number. In this case, each letter has to be converted into its position in the Latin alphabets. For example, FR would be 618. 6 for F since its position in the alphabets is 6 and 18 for R.

A huge thank you in advance

Comment: What is the first (or biggest) problem that is standing in your way?

Comment: Converting the user input into the number needed. I don't really know where to start

Comment: Well, you'd first need to get at the individual characters of the input country code; you can use the `String` method [`charAt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt-int-) for that.  You can turn a character `c` into its corresponding position in the alphabet with `c-'A'` (for an uppercase letter) or `c-'a'` (for a lowercase letter); then if `n1` and `n2` are the positions for your two letters, you could combine them with `n1 * 10 + n2`.  Does that give you somewhere to start?

Comment: Yes, this helped a lot. Thank you so much !